# IFERROR(VLOOKUP) Formula returns incorrect data in certain cells and correct data in others

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm using the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A42,SHEET2!$A$2:$N$91,11,FALSE),"")
```

Of the 100 plus rows of data, the formula has returned correct data. For the cells where the formula returns incorrect data, it appears that data from the preceeding cell (which had returned a correct value) is being returned.

For example, if in column 11 of SHEET2, the VLOOKUP value weight for product #246 is 0.04. Products #247-#300 should return the weight of 0.02. However, the formula returns 0.04.

I've painted the format for the cells that work on each sheet over the cells that haven't been working. Nothing has changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have Calculation set to manual - Change that to Automatic by using "Calculation Options" to the right of the "Formulas" tab .......or just press <kbd>F9</kbd> key to re-calculate